# Preserve content with unencoded less- and greater-than signs when using Symfony's DomCrawler

Tags: php, web-crawler, domcrawler

I'm crawling website, which text contains unencoded `<` or `>` sign.
This breaks it's content, which then appears empty.

Example

```
$html = '<div id="test-div">< 50%</div>';
$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler($html);
echo $crawler->filter('#test-div')->first()->text(); // Empty string
```

Is there a way I can still get content of `#test-div` (which I expect to be `< 50%`)?

Comment: Then that's one of the rare cases where a DOM wrapper is perhaps less suited to HTML scraping. You might want to investigate HTMLPurify to salvage it / still keep your code simpler with the DomCrawler method.

Comment: @mario thats really good idea. HTMLPurify does a little bit too much than I want, but PHP Tidy is just fine. I guess thats the solution for my problem, so please, could you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!